# How to format input in python

Tags: python

I was doing a code for a basic game and wondered if someone could help me figure out how to format the input.

```
import random
choice = str(input("1)Rock \n2)Paper\n3)Scissors\n4)Lizard\n5)Spock\nChoice: "))
computer_choice = random.randrange(5)
outcome = " "
if choice == "rock" and computer_choice == 1:
  outcome = "Tie"
```

Let's say someone was to put Rock instead of rock, or rOCk instead of rock; what can I use do so that the computer will interpret all these strings as the same. Another quick question, say someone was to input

```
"         RocK"
```

Into the input, what could I use to interpret the statement with this many spaces?

Comment: How about converting to one case and checking?

Comment: btw you use: `str(input(...` The `str()` is *always* redundant. Just use: `... = input(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use the method [`str.lower()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) in order to make all the strings with the same format. Here is an example:

```py
# example string
string = "THIS SHOULD BE LOWERCASE!"
print(string.lower())

# string with numbers
# all alphabets whould be lowercase
string = "Th!s Sh0uLd B3 L0w3rCas3!"
print(string.lower())
```

Regarding your second question you can delete the white space in different ways:

- If you want to delete only the ones on the left and on the right you can use [`str.trip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip). Here is an example:

```py
line = " this has whitespaces "
print(line.strip())
```

- If you want to delete all the whitespaces I think that the best options is to use [`str.replace()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace):

```py
line = " this has whitespaces "
print(line.replace(' ',''))
```

Comment: Hey OP! I edited my answer answering your second question. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

To get all lowercase you can use method `.lower()` and to get rid of whitespace, you can use method `.strip()`

Your code :

```
import random
choice = str(input("1)Rock \n2)Paper\n3)Scissors\n4)Lizard\n5)Spock\nChoice: ")).strip().lower()
computer_choice = random.randrange(5)
outcome = " "
if choice == "rock" and computer_choice == 1:
  outcome = "Tie"
```

And input is already a string so you don't need that `str()`

```
import random
choice = input("1)Rock \n2)Paper\n3)Scissors\n4)Lizard\n5)Spock\nChoice: ").strip().lower()
computer_choice = random.randrange(5)
outcome = " "
if choice == "rock" and computer_choice == 1:
  outcome = "Tie"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the input to lower-case using the `.lower()` string function.

```py
import random
choice = str(input("1)Rock \n2)Paper\n3)Scissors\n4)Lizard\n5)Spock\nChoice: ")).lower()
computer_choice = random.randrange(5)
outcome = " "
if choice == "rock" and computer_choice == 1:
  outcome = "Tie"
```

Comment: If you appreciate the answer, please vote up